# NodeJS / curl : change req

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I would like to change my request made using **curl**.
I need to get `req.session.co === true` to execute my action.

So, i test: `curl --request GET <url> -H req.session.co: true`

But i receive:

```
{ 
  'user-agent': ...,
  host: 'localhost:8000',
  accept: '*/*',
  'req.session.co': 'true'
}
```

The `req.session.co` *is not defined*.
This "curl" change in the header, how to change out?

Thanks !

Comment: You clearly state that you receive `'req.session.co': 'true'`; how is it also _not defined_ at the same time?

Comment: Because, in this exemple, `req.session.co` can be taken by `req.headers['req.session.co']` but not by `req.session.co`. ;)

Comment: Yes, and that is expected. How would it get from the request headers into `req.session.co` by itself?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what do you mean (i'm french). So, how can i do for set `req.session.co: true`?

Comment: Doesn't this work: `req.session.co = req.headers['req.session.co']`?

Comment: but how do that with curl ? ...

Comment: No, you can't set session data directly with `curl`. You will have to handle it on the server side.

Comment: ok so, the problem is resolved. But are you sure? Nothing apart the server can change or set the req.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set it yourself:

```
req.session.co = req.headers['req.session.co'];
```

You cannot access your session directly over HTTP, so `curl` can not affect it in any way.